# JSF Cascading Style Sheet not applied when page redirected via listener

Tags: jsf-2

I have the follwing listener used via f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{sessionCheck.loginVerify}"/ in my jsf page:

```
public void loginVerify() {
  try {
    ExternalContext    eCTX    = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext() ;
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();

    // eCTX.redirect(eCTX.getRequestContextPath() + "/index.xhtml");
    eCTX.dispatch("/index.xhtml");
  } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {}
}
```

However when I use redirect or disptach the style sheet is not applied to the index page.
The style sheet reference in index xhtml is:

```
<link href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/css/myStyles.css" rel="styleSheet" type="text/css"/>
```

I have tried adding the following style sheet ref but it made no difference:

```
<link href="/resources/css/m450.css" rel="styleSheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Has anyone had to solve such a problem please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one should work fine, although it can be simplified as

```
<link href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/css/myStyles.css" rel="styleSheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Rightclick the page in the webbrowser and choode *View Source*, is the EL been evaluated? If you're using Firefox, you can click on the `href`, does it show the right CSS? Turn on Firebug, check the *Net* tab, does the CSS get loaded properly?

Comment: The first time the index page is rendered everything is fine but after session expiry my listener does a dispatch (or redirect, it doesnt make any diff in this case) to the index page.  Below I'm showing a snippet of the index rendered code before session expiry and after session expiry.  I hasten to add that I'm using Tomcat 7 Form authentication.  This is the code before: <link href="/myApp/resources/css/myStyle.css" rel="styleSheet"... then after the disptach is: <link href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/css/myStyle.css"...

Comment: So, you see it straight in the page source as the webbrowser has retrieved? In other words, the EL is not been evaluated?

Comment: yes, this is what appears to be happening after the listener carries out the dispatch/redirect.

Comment: OK, then the dispatched URL does not match the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet`. In other words, you didn't map it on `*.xhtml`, but on something different, such as `*.jsf`. You need to alter the dispatch URL accordingly.

Comment: OK, I changed the disptach URL to index.jsf but this time I get the error: The requested resource (/myApp/index.jsf) is not available.  I will see if I can configure the mapping to cater for both...

Comment: Aha! I will try that.  I was just checking web.xml and the faces servlet mapping is: <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Comment: Yes, redirect to `/faces/index.xhtml`. Or better, change the mapping by `*.xhtml`, but you have to change all existing `/faces` links in your webapp, if any.

Comment: Hey man!  I expect you knew this already but it works now !  Thanks a mil.  This means that I now have a solution (although without an intervening "sorry your session has expired" page) for the issue of how j_security_check gets in the way when sessions expire  and post payload is lost.

Comment: I have clicked on the only check mark I see next to your original reply.  Thanks again.